# Failed to build GCC 10 from source

Tags: c++, gcc

On Oracle Linux, I'm trying to build a GCC toolchain from the following:

- GCC 10.1.0
- binutils 2.34
- GDB 9.2.0

All of these are the latest released sources as of today.
I've configured like so:

```sh
../gcc10-toolchain/configure \
    --prefix=/opt/gcc10-toolchain \
    --with-diagnostics-color=auto \
    --with-system-zlib \
    --with-system-lzma \
    --enable-languages="c,c++,lto" \
    --enable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --enable-gold=default \
    --enable-install-libbfd \
    --enable-plugins \
    --enable-default-pie \
    --enable-linker-build-id \
    --enable-threads=posix \
    --enable-checking=release \
    --enable-__cxa_atexit \
    --enable-initfini-array \
    --enable-gnu-indirect-function \
    --enable-tui \
    --enable-bootstrap \
    --disable-multilib \
    --disable-libgcj \
    --disable-nls \
    --disable-lto \
    --disable-libstdcxx-debug
```

However, when building with `make`, I get the following errors:

```
../../gcc10-toolchain/gcc/lto-streamer-out.c: In function ‘void write_symbol_extension_info(tree)’: ../../gcc10-toolchain/gcc/lto-streamer-out.c:2790:10: error: ‘GCCST_VARIABLE’ was not declared in this scope
        ? GCCST_VARIABLE : GCCST_FUNCTION);
          ^ ../../gcc10-toolchain/gcc/lto-streamer-out.c:2790:27: error: ‘GCCST_FUNCTION’ was not declared in this scope
        ? GCCST_VARIABLE : GCCST_FUNCTION);
                           ^ ../../gcc10-toolchain/gcc/lto-streamer-out.c:2797:18: error: ‘GCCSSK_BSS’ was not declared in this scope   section_kind |= GCCSSK_BSS;
```

Unfortunately I could not find anything on this online, and have no idea where to even begin looking.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was the order in which I copied the sources together. binutils-2.34 is older than gcc-10.1.0, and so gcc-10.1.0 be copied in last so that it overwrites the files shared with binutils, not the other way around.